# Java out of memory error during the installation processor of netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting java out of memory error when try to install netbeans.

## System :

```
Linux shantanu 3.11.0-14-generic 
#21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 17:04:55 UTC 2013 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 13.10
```

## Download netbeans from [here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=linux&lang=en&option=cpp)

## Error log is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6508753/)

[image]

## java -version

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.12) (7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

What is the problem exactly ?! How can i solve this problem? I am also running eclipse smoothly.

Comment: paste here the log file

Comment: @Sushantp606 I already did. Please check out the section "Error Log here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Netbeans fails to load in default java heap size. You have to forcefully increase JVM's heap size by exporting _JAVA_OPTIONS

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx300m -Xms300m"
```

Now it's working.

Comment: @Sushantp606 Can't(no option), wait for 2 days to accept this.